# search for a field between two dates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My information in database is weak and I do not know how to use queries. I have searched the web and I learned few thing about making queries and I found an example but i do not know how to use it in vb.net.
The query in SQL server will be like this:

```
 select hb from gen where date between 12/6/2014 and 16/6/2014
```

It works fine, but i don't know how to use it in vb.net
so wrote this line of code and i think my solution will be something like this:

```
BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("select hb from gen where date between" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "and" & GENDateTimePicker1.Value)
```

so what is wrong with this line

Comment: This is why you should build strings out before using them; inspection becomes so much easier. In this case, you could inspect the value of Filter and verify it. between is missing a space after it; and is missing spaces around it; your dates aren't wrapped in apostrophes. *assuming MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution which i made after hard searching and a lot of lectures in vb.net and SQL server "Excuse me I am a beginner"

```
                Me.BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format(" date <= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND Date >= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}# and hb like'" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value)
```

and "hb" is the name of the field which i want to find
thank you for your time and the fast respond

Answer (score 1):

If you'd read the documentation then you'd know that the `BindingSource.Filter` property requires dates to be expressed in the format #M/dd/yyyy#.  Also, the `String` represents just a `WHERE` clause, not an entire query.  You're not using `String.Format` properly either.  Your code should be:

```
BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("[Date] BETWEEN #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", DateTimePicker1.Value, GENDateTimePicker1.Value)
```

Comment: well .. i have used this line before but the problem is i don't want every thing between two dates i want the field hb between two dates

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to use your sql query in vb.net:

First, you want to setup your connection string to your database. Next, you can declare a string with the contents of your sql statement. Third, you'll want to setup a using statement that will close the sql connection when it exits. I would also read up on parameterized sql to mitigate attacks on your database.

```
Dim con As String = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGNAME").ConnectionString)
Dim result as String = String.Empty 'set the result to whatever the datatype of hb is in your database
Dim query as String = "select hb from gen where date between '12-6-2014' and '16-6-2014'"
     Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(con)
          Try
               conn.Open()
               Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn)
               command.Connection = conn
               command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

               result = command.ExecuteScalar()
               conn.Close()
               conn.Dispose()
          Catch ex As Exception
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
          End Try
     End Using
```

Comment: i want to use bindingsource.filter it is easier for my low experience

Comment: Are you trying to filter your datasource or query the database? You don't specify in your question.

Comment: I think it's the same, in the end I want my code to deliver to the user   a particular field between two dates